# How to display ads in UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, applovin

I want to implement AppLovin Max ads in my app , previously i was working with adMob , but now the problem is i don’t know how to implement ads in custom UIView , i can display ads at bottom but i want to show ads inside the post,, here is the link to display ad

```
func createBannerAd()
       {
           adView = MAAdView(adUnitIdentifier: “”)
           adView.delegate = self
       
           // Banner height on iPhone and iPad is 50 and 90, respectively
           let height: CGFloat = (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad) ? 90 : 90
           
           let theHeight = view.frame.size.height //grabs the height of your view
       
           // Stretch to the width of the screen for banners to be fully functional
           let width: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
       
           adView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: theHeight - 70, width: width, height: height)
       
           // Set background or background color for banners to be fully functional
           adView.backgroundColor = .white
           
          
       
           view.addSubview(adView)
           
       
           // Load the first ad
           adView.loadAd()
       }
```

how can i add this ad to my custom UIView ?

i have tried like this

```
func createBannerAd()
       {
           adView = MAAdView(adUnitIdentifier: “”)
           adView.delegate = self

           adView.backgroundColor = .white
           
          
       
           view.addSubview(customUIVIEW)
           
        adView.loadAd()
       }
```

but it did not work , please help

Comment: What exactly doesn’t work?

Comment: Copy and paste that code into a UIViewController